# UICollectionView column grid gaps

Tags: objective-c, ios, uicollectionview

I am using `UICollectionView` flow layout in my **iPad** application. I have cells with different width and heights. When I used subclass of `UICollectionViewFlowLayout` as layout for collection  view, it shows me gaps between cells.

If there is large cell in column, it makes grid and small cells of that column get render centered of that large cell in column. **Is there any better way to tight cell wrapping?**

I am using horizontal scrolling. I tried using `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` method, but didn't get succeed into that.

Please let me know if anyone has done same kind of thing by using `layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:` method or by other way...

Please find attached image. I need same kind of solution[image]

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1):

**Use like this**

```
UICollectionViewFlowLayout *layout=[[UICollectionViewFlowLayout alloc] init];

layout.minimumInteritemSpacing = 0;
layout.minimumLineSpacing = 2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I subclassed UICollectionViewFlowLayout and in both my layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath: and  layoutAttributesForElementsInRect: methods I have one method called

```
setLineAttributes:(UICollectionViewLayoutAttributes *)attributes visibleRect:(CGRect)visibleRect:
```

which contains:

```
if (attributes.indexPath.item == 0 || attributes.indexPath.item == 1 || attributes.indexPath.item == 2) {
    CGRect f = attributes.frame;
    f.origin.x = 0;
    attributes.frame = f;
} else {
    NSIndexPath *ipPrev = [NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:attributes.indexPath.item - 3 inSection:attributes.indexPath.section];
    CGRect fPrev = [self layoutAttributesForItemAtIndexPath:ipPrev].frame;
    CGFloat rightPrev = fPrev.origin.x + fPrev.size.width + 10;
    if (attributes.frame.origin.x <= rightPrev) 
        return;

    CGRect f = attributes.frame;
    f.origin.x = rightPrev;
    attributes.frame = f;
}
```

Comment: In above code you have assume there will be 3 rows. But that will not be case always. Suppose my application don't know width and height of each cell (suppose it is coming from server or it will decide run time), in that case we need to calculate number of rows and columns manually. And then we need to calculate each cell origin  based on adjacent cell frame. I am not aware whether this is best way or there is something else. But anyways Thanks for your reply.

Comment: Wouldn't the number of rows always be the same, not necessarily 3, but always a set number of rows.

Comment: yes.. but collection view doesnt provide number of rows and columns. When we are having different size of (width and height) items, we need to to manually calculate number of rows and columns also. Is there any better way?